# Postfix while using relayhost sends local emails to root

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server

I've recently configured a web-server without mail-server inside it. Beside that I use another server to get incoming emails to mydomain (MX record ip is different than web-server ip). Also I configured postfix to send emails via smtp relay host for outgoing emails from web server.
The problem is that: All outgoing emails to other domains work fine but when web app tries to send an email to mydomain emails (e.g support@mydomain.com), it goes to  and It can't be delivered. 
Here is my `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mydomain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination =  $myhostname, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = smtp.emailsmtpprovider.com:2525
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = static:something@somewhere.com:xxxxx-xxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
header_size_limit = 4096000
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Here is my `/etc/postfix/virtual` content:

```
root     root@localhost
```

Here is my `/etc/aliases` content:

```
postmaster:    root
```

Here is my `/etc/mailname` content:

```
mydomain.com
```

Finally here is my `/var/log/mail.log` related content:

```
Mar 27 12:30:06 web-server-01 postfix/cleanup[25232]: 240BF1F5FA5: message-id=<20180327123006.240BF1F5FA5@mydomain.com>
Mar 27 12:30:06 web-server-01 postfix/qmgr[24992]: 240BF1F5FA5: from=<root@mydomin.com>, size=804, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 27 12:30:06 web-server-01 postfix/local[25234]: 240BF1F5FA5: to=<root@localhost>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.04, delays=0.02/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Mar 27 12:30:06 web-server-01 postfix/qmgr[24992]: 240BF1F5FA5: removed
```

I've googled it a lot but have not proceeded at all. I'd appreciate if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue here is that you have `myhostname = mydomain.com` and then `mydestination =  $myhostname, localhost.localdomain, localhost`

This is causing postfix to handle all mail for mydomain.com as local.  If you set as follows, the issue should be fixed.

```
myhostname = hostname.mydomain.com
mydomain = mydomain.com
```

If you are looking for something that will simply relay email from the local host over to the relay, you might consider ssmtp